# Linq query distinct values of date for last 7 days, exception thrown when running query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a table Employee where I retrieved the Id and Name fields by:

```
var users = context.Employees.ToList()
                   .Select(employee => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(employee.Id,employee.Name));
```

That part works fine, my problem is that there is another table Attendance where foreign keys are set and there is a field LoginDate which is a DateTime value. A user can login multiple times so I want to get distinct values of how many times a user has logged in in the last 7 days.

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    var days = context.Attendances.Where(x => x.Id == user.Key && x.LoginDate.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)).Distinct().ToList();
     int count = days.Count();
     _attendanceTable.Rows.Add(user.Key, user.Value, count);
 }
```

I am getting an exception when I'm running the query for Attendance table:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do all in single query:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date; // I think you need date only here
var query = from e in context.Employees
            join a in context.Attendances on e.Id equals a.Id into g
            select new
            {
                e.Id,
                e.Name,
                Count = g.Where(x => x.LoginDate > date)
                         .GroupBy(x = > new {
                               x.LoginDate.Year,
                               x.LoginDate.Month,
                               x.LoginDate.Day 
                          }).Count()
            };

foreach(var user in query)
   _attendanceTable.Rows.Add(user.Id, user.Name, user.Count);
```

Also `Date` property of DateTime is not supported by EntityFramework. You should use anonymous object for grouping attendances by date part.

Generated SQL query will look like:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
       [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            DATEPART (year, [Extent2].[LoginDate]) AS [C1], 
            DATEPART (month, [Extent2].[LoginDate]) AS [C2],
            DATEPART (day, [Extent2].[LoginDate]) AS [C2],
            FROM [dbo].[Attendances] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        )  AS [Distinct1]) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: Awesome, this query is beautiful! Can you please edit your post and give a very brief explanation of the process of your query. I already chose this as best answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shahnawaz first part is joining employees and attendances (it is something like left join). Second part is sub-query for joined attendances `g` which filters attendances by date, then group filtered attendances by year,month,day (btw you can group only by day, if you selecting attendances for last week)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i have a table that has these two columns salesOrderDate and TotaltAmount the salesOrderDate is DateTime Type 
i want list of data of last 7 days which  has only salesorderdate("yyyy-MM-dd") and amount if the date is repeated then it should sum the amount with record of same date and give result as total amount on that particular date

Answer (score 2):

Some of the operations you can perform in code don't translate (at least not cleanly) to SQL, you'll need to move around certain operations so they translate better.

```
//Figure out the day you want in advance
var sevenDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
var results = users.Select(user => new {
     user.Key,
     user.Value,
     Count = users.Join(context.Attendances, 
                        user => user.Key,
                        attendance => attendance.EmployeeId,
                        (user, attendance) => attendance.LoginDate)
                  .Where(date => date > sevenDaysAgo)
                  .Select(date => date.Day)
                  .Distinct()
                  .Count()
});

foreach (var result in results)
{        
    _attendanceTable.Rows.Add(result.Key, result.Value, result.Count);
}
```

Comment: this is not solving the issue, I am still getting this exception:
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @Shahnawaz you changed `x.LoginDate.Date` to `x.LoginDate` right?

Comment: Oh yes I changed it now, I am getting 0 days for every employee.

Comment: @Shahnawaz do you really mean to use the `Id` of the `Attendance` table to join to the `Key` of the `User`?

Comment: @mlorbetske doing `ToList()` will significantly harm performance - each iteration will be separate query to server and all attendances will be loaded to memory

Comment: @mlorbetske I have given you +1 reputation for your effort, I had to edit your query though a bit to get what I want. Thanks a lot though :)